# Getting output from the random Python module

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to run a script that takes five functions in a list, and picks one at random using the `random` module.

```
myList = [quote1(), quote2(), quote3(), quote4(), quote5()]

def random_output(): random.choice(myList)

print(random_output)
```

However, upon running, it just prints all of the quotes at the same time, followed by `<function random_output at 0x0000019F66EF4430>`.

Comment: You didn't call your function. Also your function is missing a return.

Comment: You seem to be calling functions (quote1 etc) when you don't mean to and not calling `random_output` when you do mean to.

Comment: It's hard to give solid advice without knowing exactly what you're trying to do. What are these `quote` functions? Do they need input? Seeing what kinds of inputs your problem has, and what kind of outputs you expect, would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your functions in `myList`, **not the result of their call**. Then call the function after selecting it with `random.choice`:

```
myList = [quote1, quote2, quote3, quote4, quote5]

def random_output():
    # select a random function
    # call it, and return its output
    return random.choice(myList)()

print(random_output())
```

Comment: This almost worked, as it is printing a random quote, however it is also just printing "none" in the line below it.

Comment: Maybe the functions have a `print` inside? In this case just do `random_output()`, not `print(random_output())`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function A that just calls another function B. Just call function B:

```
import random

myList = [quote1(), quote2(), quote3(), quote4(), quote5()]
random.choice(myList)
```

If you *really* want to put it in a function, maybe because you are doing other thing in there, you should always pass in what your function needs, and return what it produces (this is called a 'pure' function):

```
def random_output(aList):
    return random.choice(aList)
```

Then call it like:

```
random_output(myList)
```

If you don't want to call the functions `quote1`, `quote2` etc yet, then you should not put parentheses after them until you do want to call them. For example:

```
funcs = [quote1, quote2, quote3, quote4, quote5]
random_func = random.choice(funcs)
result = random_func(my_input)
```